# How to use "this" with object spread to set class properties

Tags: javascript, class, object, syntax, this

Can i do this in one line without the intermitten variables.

```js
const { state$, toggleState } = StateManagement.useToggleState$(initialState);
this.layoutState$ = state$;
this.toggleState = toggleState;
```

Something like this

```js
{ state$: this.layoutState$, toggleState: this.toggleState } = StateManagement.useToggleState$(initialState);
```

When I wrap it in paranthesis like below, the IDE stops throwing errors, but they are not actually assigned.

```js
({ state$: this.layoutState$, toggleState: this.toggleState } = StateManagement.useToggleState$(initialState));
```

Comment: Please include a [mcve] because the last piece of code [seems to work fine (using regular object)](https://jsbin.com/jiyibev/1/edit?js,console) as well as [using class syntax](https://jsbin.com/gobahuv/1/edit?js,console).

Answer (score -1):

Apparently my problem came from typescript not doing its thing when you assign a declared property in the constructor (Inferring its type). So, I just needed to manually write its type in the declaration.

```js
toggleLayoutState: (key: keyof LayoutState) => void;

constructor() {
    ({ state$: this.layoutState$, toggleState: this.toggleLayoutState } = StateManagement.useToggleState$(initialState));
}
```

Normally it should understand the type, even if you don't explicitly state it. Something to fix by typescript contributors maybe, or I am missing something.

PS: Not deleting the question, since it would have helped me if it existed before. Mods can delete it If I am breaking any rules I guess.